# Windows authentication for SignalR service hosted in Kestrel (AspNet Core 5.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, kestrel-http-server

I have a SignalR (AspNet Core 5.0) hosted in a console app using Kestrel as the web host.

I want to access the user Identity of any request in a Hub implementation, when accessing the following the Identity values are NULL.

I've looked at the available documentation on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) and made the following changes, but not getting the Identity populated as I expected, also not finding any examples for AspNet Core 5.0 anywhere.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
public class ExampleHub : Hub
{
   public Task Foo()
   {
      *// why is name NULL?*
      var name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
              
      return Task.Completed;
   }
}
```

I have added the following line when configuring the services as StartUp:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNeogtiate();
   services.AddSignalR(options => options.EnableDetailedErrors = true);
   ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseRouting();
   app.UseAuthentication();

   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapHub<ExampleHub>("/Example"); });
}
```

Comment: Where's the authorize attribute?

Comment: So I need the attribute even if I want access to the identity?

Comment: Are you allowing anonymous and logged in users? Who is enforcing that the user has an identity?

Comment: I want logged in users only, so adding the Authorize, i now get failed to invoke, because user is unauthorized...

Comment: Sounds like progress! Now you have to find out why the client is unauthorized

Comment: Identity is not populated with Kestrel, it is with HttpSys, answer below

Comment: I believe thats because you need to do the challenge earlier then when the hub tries to connect. https://scottsauber.com/2020/01/20/globally-require-authenticated-users-by-default-using-fallback-policies-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Fallback doesn't help...

Comment: DOH! - Missing app.UseAuthentication() in Startup Configure method.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working by changing to HttpSys instead of Kestrel as the host. The `Context.User.Identity` is now populated as `WindowsIdentity`.

In this case using HttpSys is preferred - an internal (corporate) network hosted in a Windows Service instead of a web server (IIS). Note IIS also uses HttpSys internally.